# Respuesa de AJAX deja de funcionar

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema con mi respuesta AJAX.

La situación es la siguiente: un cliente agrega productos a su carrito de compras. Si agrega uno o dos productos, AJAX ejecuta la función de success, y el sistema registra en la base de datos correctamente todas las compras.

**Ahora, el problema: si el cliente agrega 3 o más productos, el sistema sigue registrando correctamente las compras en la base de datos, PERO NO ejecuta la función de AJAX.**

He hecho var_dump para ver que llegaba en el $arrayCompleto para el caso de 3 productos, y efectivamente llegan 3. No hay problema con lo que llega.

Les comparto el pedazito de código de AJAX, y los dos archivos PHP llamados "auxiliar.php" y "carrito.controlador.php":

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({                        
   type: "POST",                 
   url: rutaOculta+"controladores/auxiliar.php",                 
   data: { arrayCompleto : arrayCompleto, usuario : usuarioEnvio, direccion1 : direccion1Envio, direccion2 : direccion2Envio, dia : diaEnvio, hora : horaEnvio, email : emailEnvio, telefono : telefonoEnvio, sesion : sesion }, 
   success: function(response){

    localStorage.removeItem("listaProductos");
    localStorage.removeItem("cantidadCesta");
    localStorage.removeItem("sumaCesta");
    window.location = rutaOculta + "perfil";

   }

});
```

**auxiliar.php:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){

require ('carrito.controlador.php');

$arrayCompleto = json_decode($_POST['arrayCompleto'], true);

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$direccion1 = $_POST['direccion1'];
$direccion2 = $_POST['direccion2'];
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$hora = $_POST['hora'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$sesion = $_POST['sesion'];


$payments = new ControladorCompras();
$payments -> ctrCompraEfectivo($arrayCompleto, $usuario, $direccion1, $direccion2, $dia, $hora, $email, $telefono, $sesion);

}
```

**carrito.controlador.php**

```
class ControladorCompras {

    public function ctrCompraEfectivo(&$arrayCompleto, &$usuario, &$direccion1, &$direccion2, &$dia, &$hora, &$email, &$telefono, &$sesion){

        if(isset($usuario)){

            if(preg_match('/^(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$/', $direccion1) &&
               preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,16}$/', $telefono)) {

                  #Actualizamos la base de datos
                  for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCompleto); $i++){

                     $datos = array("idUsuario"=> $sesion,
                                    "idProducto"=> $arrayCompleto[$i]["idProducto"],
                                    "metodo"=> "Efectivo",
                                    "email"=> $email,
                                    "direccion"=> $direccion1,
                                    "detalleDireccion"=> $direccion2,
                                    "diaEnvio"=> $dia,
                                    "horaEnvio"=> $hora,
                                    "telefono"=> $telefono,
                                    "pais"=> "ARG");

                     $respuesta = ControladorCarrito::ctrNuevasComprasEfectivo($datos);

                     $ordenar = "id";
                     $item = "id";
                     $valor = $arrayCompleto[$i]["idProducto"];

                     require_once ('../controladores/productos.controlador.php');

                     $productosCompra = ControladorProductos::ctrListarProductosEfectivo($ordenar, $item, $valor);

                     foreach ($productosCompra as $key => $value) {

                        $item1 = "ventas";
                        $valor1 = $value["ventas"] + $arrayCompleto[$i]["cantidad"];
                        $item2 = "id";
                        $valor2 =$value["id"];

                        $actualizarCompra = ControladorProductos::ctrActualizarProducto($item1, $valor1, $item2, $valor2);  

                     }         

                }

            } else {

                echo '<script> 

                            swal({
                                  type: "error",
                                  title: "Oops...",
                                  text: "Hay algo que no está bien. Vuelva a completar la información de envío."
                                });

                    </script>';

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Primer recomendación:** debes manejar las excepciones en PHP en todos los lugares y mas cuando vas y vienes de la base de datos. El ajax no esta mal, lo que tienes mal es algo en php que no termino de ejecutarse correctamente y no sabes que es. Por lo que un try catch deberia decirte por donde podria estar el problema.

**Segunda recomendación:** Agrega error a tu AJAX, en el puedes hacer que haga ciertas cosas cuando la respuesta de tu servidor ha sido negativa o directamente ha fallado

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    success: function (response) {
      //Tus funciones en caso de que todo salga bien
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
     //Tus funciones en caso de error en servidor
    },
});
```

*PD: Si metes tu codigo de success en function error deberia dejarte seguir adelante pero no lo recomiendo para nada, simplemente estarias ignorando el error*

Comment: Gracias por tus recomendaciones. Por otro lado, podrías darme un ejemplo de try catch?

Comment: Claro, buscando un poco encontré el siguiente enlace el cual te podria ayudar bastante para usar los try catch y entenderlos. https://diego.com.es/excepciones-en-php

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Ahora me pondré a leer.